# ListBox - value being set to text field

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, listbox

Problem: 
When adding list item the Value field is being set to the Text field.  Initially I though the problem was related to the input parameter for the primary key ( group_type_id ) as it is configured as OUTPUT variable.

Interesting enough, when I Watch all of the values, everything is correct. 
So for example, I'll watch these:

```
ddr["group_type_name"]   comes out as "Dept"
ddr["grouptypeid"] comes out as 4
```

When the item is created however,

```
itms.TEXT = "Dept"
itms.Value = "Dept"  <-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
```

I'm at a loss why the listbox values are being set to the text values when I can clearly see the data reader values are correct. ?

Code sample here:

```
DbDataReader ddr = grp.GetGroupTypeList(grp);
if (ddr.HasRows)
{
    ListItem itm = new ListItem();
    itm.Text = "Select Group";
    itm.Value = "0";
    lb.Items.Add(itm);
    while (ddr.Read())
    {
        ListItem itms = new ListItem(ddr["group_type_name"] as string, ddr["grouptypeid"] as string);
    }
    lb.SelectedValue = lbSelected;            
}
```

procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[asp_Group_Type]
@driver             char(1)='I',
@group_type_id      int=null OUTPUT,
@group_type_name    varchar(50)=null,
@par_group_id       int=null,
@active             bit 
AS
DECLARE @SQL    varchar(8000)
DECLARE @boolWhere varchar(10)
SET @boolWhere = ' WHERE ' 

SET NOCOUNT ON

IF (@driver = 'I')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO  [dbo].[group_type]
       ([group_type_name],
        [Par_Group_Id])
     VALUES
       (RTRIM(LTRIM(@group_type_name)),
        @par_group_id)

        SELECT @group_type_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
    END

IF (@driver = 'U')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  [dbo].[group_type]
           SET [group_type_name] = RTRIM(LTRIM(@group_type_name))
              ,[Par_Group_Id] = @par_group_id
         WHERE [group_type_id] = @group_type_id
    END

IF (@driver = 'S')
    BEGIN


        SET @SQL = ' SELECT  [group_type_id] AS [grouptypeid], [group_type_id], [group_type_name],[Par_Group_Id]  FROM [dbo].[group_type] '

        IF (@group_type_id > 0)
            BEGIN
                SET @SQL = @SQL + @boolWhere + '[group_type_id] = ''' + CAST(@group_type_id AS VARCHAR) + ''''
                SET @boolWhere = ' AND '
            END 

        IF (@active > 0)
            BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + @boolWhere + ' [active] = ''' + CAST(@active AS VARCHAR) + ''''
            END 

        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' ORDER BY [group_type_name] '
        PRINT(@SQL)
        EXEC(@SQL)
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly the `as string` that is causing the problems.  "as" will default to `null` if it can't do the conversion.  A ListItem will set the Value to the same as the Text if the Value isn't a valid string. Instead use `ddr["grouptypeid"].ToString()`.

Comment: Then please mark my answer as the one that answered your question.